# Second line of equation shifted

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

How is it possible to move the second line of the equation to begin few spaces to the right like this:

[image]

So all the after lines will start at the same place.

My code looks as following:

```
\begin{align}
&b_{PWM}(t) = D + \frac{M}{2} \text{cos}(\omega_{1}t + \theta_{1})
\\
&+ \sum_{m=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{m\pi} \left\{\text{sin}\left[m(\omega_{c}t+\theta_{c})\right] -J_{0}(m\pi M) \cdot \text{sin} \left[m(\omega_{c}t+\theta_{c}) - 2mD\pi \right] \right\}
\\
& + \sum_{m=1}^{+\infty} \sum_{n=\pm 1}^{\pm \infty} \frac{J_{n}(m \pi M)}{m \pi} \cdot \text{sin} \left[ \frac{n \pi}{2} - m(\omega_{c}t + \theta_{c}) -n(\omega_{1}t + \theta_{1}) +2mD \pi \right]
\end{align}
```

and the result I get is:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Please help us with a code showing your problem. What you want to achieve is not clear.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) assuming you are using `align*` from `amsmath`, align on the right of the `=` by using `= {} &` and align in front of the `+` on the second line using `& +`

Comment: `\text{cos}` is really wrong: `\cos` is the command to use. Similarly for the sine.

Comment: The last image does not correspond to the code given. Also please always post full minimal examples not just sniplets where others have to guess the test of the document in order to test your code.

Answer (score 2):

If the equation is unnumbered, use  `align*` from the `amsmath` environment, and set the alignment points to, say,  `+`. If the equation is numbered, insert a `split` or an `aligned` environment within `equation`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

  \begin{equation}
\begin{split}b_{\mathrm{bwp}}(t) = D & +\frac{M}{2}\cos(ω_1t + θ_1) \\
& + \sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{m\pi}\sin[m(ω_ct + θ_c)]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get error saying split won't work here

Comment: I can't really understand the difference between “numbered” and “unnumbered”. The solution with `split` is the same whether you embed it either in `equation` or in `equation*`.

Comment: What I had in head is that for unnumbered equation, one doesn't have to nest an environment within another. A single `align*` will do (b.t.w., thanks for the edit!)

Comment: @Bernard Yes, it would do, but at the expense of uniformity. Say the coauthor or advisor tells you “that equation *must* be numbered”, you have to change `align*` into `equation` with a nested split; if you use `equation*` from the outset, you have just to remove a couple of asterisks.

Comment: @ben No, in the example it works, so you seem to be doing something different. We can't know what.

Answer (score 0):

With `align` environment it should be very simple, just add this symbol "&" before the "=" symbol, like this: "& =", see below simple example:

```
\begin{align}

A & = B + B + B

\\\

& = C + C + C

\\\\[2pt]

& = D + D + D

\end{align}
```

% Note that The [2pt] is just to space between the equation's lines if you like, you can remove it.

Comment: This does neither address nor solve OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `IEEEeqnarray` environment from the `IEEEtrantools` package can be used. As the 2nd and 3rd lines overlap with equation no, `IEEEeqnarraynumspace` command can be used to avoid that. If equation no is not expected, they can be suppressed by using the `*` version of the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
b_{PWM}(t) & = & D + \frac{M}{2} \cos(\omega_{1}t + \theta_{1})
\\
           &   & \negmedspace {} + \sum_{m=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{m\pi} \left\{\sin\left[m(\omega_{c}t+\theta_{c})\right] -J_{0}(m\pi M) \cdot \text{sin} \left[m(\omega_{c}t+\theta_{c}) - 2mD\pi \right] \right\}
\IEEEeqnarraynumspace\\
           &   & \negmedspace {} + \sum_{m=1}^{+\infty} \sum_{n=\pm 1}^{\pm \infty} \frac{J_{n}(m \pi M)}{m \pi} \cdot \text{sin} \left[ \frac{n \pi}{2} - m(\omega_{c}t + \theta_{c}) -n(\omega_{1}t + \theta_{1}) +2mD \pi \right]
\IEEEeqnarraynumspace
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{document}
```

[image]